# Can't change Dateformat in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I can't change date format in Hive, please find the reference below.

AnalysisException: optigo_data.date_format() unknown---error for data format conversion
ex:2015-09-28 21:07:51 to 28-sep-2016
DATE_FORMAT(' 2015-09-28   ','%d-%b-%y')

Answer (score 1):

Supported formats are Java SimpleDateFormat formats – https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use regex call. try it out.

Below link might be helpful to you.

https://qnalist.com/questions/4658026/date-format-in-hive